# gdal_rasterize : getting area not in or touching polygon (options -at and -i)

Tags: raster, shapefile, gdal, polygon

I would like to capture the area that is not in a polygon (option -i) and that doesn't touch that polygon.

`gdal_rasterize -at` will return the polygon + edges, but `gdal_rasterize -at -i` will not invert `gdal_rasterize -at`, but will add pixels on edges to `gdal_rasterize`.

As a result, the burned area includes the edges, which is not what I want. I was hoping `-at -i` would have a different result than `-i -at`, but it didn't.

Is there a simple way of burning everything that is [not inside the polygon OR not on the edge of the polygon] ?

Answer (score 2):

Gdal_rasterize uses the center of the pixel. As a workaround I would either rasterize a buffer around your input polygon (with half pixel size) or apply mathematical morphology on the result (aka erosion of one pixel)

Comment: This is indeed my plan so far (rasterize a buffer). I was looking for something available within gdal to perform this - I hope that, since `-at` has been implemented, there might have been a need for "`-nt`" (not touched). Apparently not...